# Android: getIntent().getStringExtra(); doesn't return any value from database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-cardview

I have been writing an app that has a CardView. In order to store all the data, and later to retrieve data to the CardView, I have successfully  connected my app to the Firebase Database, and I have created my database that looks like this:
[My data base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j6nT.png)

The block of code that apparently reading from the database and referring it to the CardView works quietly well except one particular line that doesn't return any value.
Here is the code:

```
         //get data from intent
    byte[] bytes = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
    String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
    String desc = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");
    String expl = getIntent().getStringExtra("explanation");

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

    //set data to views
    titleTv.setText(title);
    detailTv.setText(desc);
    explanTv.setText(expl);
    imageIv.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    //get image from imageview as bitmap
    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)mImageIv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

The line of the code that returns null is this one:

```
String expl = getIntent().getStringExtra("explanation");
```

I have also tried to fetch it with a listener but there I am getting something that makes me even more confused. So as you can see in my database I have a child called "explanation" under the parent "Data" for all my items that I want to show in the cards. Each item has a different explanation value... if I try to refer this child using a listener in order to get a value, then all my items will get the same explanation and that explanation will come from the last item. So listener will refer one value to all my items instead of referring the particular explanation to the certain item. This is the listener I have implemented:

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mDbRef = database.child("Data");
    mDbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String expl = ds.child("explanation").getValue(String.class);
                mExplanTv.setText(expl);

                Log.i("TAG", "Explanation = " + message.explanation);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

            Log.w("TAG", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    })
```

Comment: Log.i("TAG", "Explanation = " + message.explanation); don't bother with this line of code it's from different implementation that I had tried before in order to see what it will return

Comment: Show us how you add that data to the intent. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Alex, thank you so much for your response, but in the meanwhile, I have solved this problem. It was a really silly mistake... I added that String after I created my adapter class so I completely forgot to add it to that class. :/ I guess it's just a beginner's mistake...